# Zope external editor with upload-on-save (Notepad++ prefered)

Tags: editor, zope

We are doing webdevelopment with [Zope](http://www.zope.org/).
The web-editor is just horrible. No syntax highlighting, no in-text-tabs, nothing you can work with.

I installed [Zope External Editor](http://www.plope.com/software/ExternalEditor). It is now possible that I click the "use external editor" button on every element and it creates a temporary file and opens it in Notepad++, awesome.

But one important thing fail: it doesn't save back to Zope when I save the file. I still have to copy the code back to Zope manually.

I also searched for syntax highlighting extension for chrome/firefox at least to highlight the code (but I prefer Notepad++ with upload-on-save).

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you also download the ExternalEditor Helper application?

Your browser should open the helper application, which will then open the editor (which you can specify in the configuration, see last point below). This is important because the helper application is responsible for sending changes back to Zope, which it does by keeping an open WebDAV session while you are editing.

You should download the latest helper app here: http://plone.org/products/zope-externaleditor-client

**From that page:**

- Under Windows: Install the windows binary executable.
- Open your page in your web browser and click on the link 'edit with external       application'
- Associate the file with Zope External Editor and make it permanent (first time only)
- The file is opened in the editor defined in windows registry with certain editors, a message will ask whether the edition is terminated or not;
- keep it until you closed you file and say yes.
- If you want to change your default editor for certain content types , or if you want to       add proxy parameters, open Zope External Edit in your program files menu and change your local user configuration.

Comment: I go down on my knees - virtually! Really dude, you made my day. Works fine, WebDAV locks file, I love it. Looks like the site I got External Editor from is out of date and your site simply holds the new version of this program. Damn.

Comment: I've had my fair share struggling with External Editor. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to **not** develop Zope applications through-the-web anymore.

Use proper python packages, and you'll get to use your favourite tools without difficult integration with the server.